# How to Disinfect a Bansuri?

Tags: indian-classical, instrument-cleaning, bansuri

I am seeing different ways on Internet to disinfect a Bansuri.

One person suggested submerging in water and then hold over an open flame (this doesn't sound like good idea, especially with the nylon bindings)

What is best way to disinfect Bansuri. How often to disinfect Bansuri?

I had a bad cough past month. Finally I started practicing again (past 2 to 3 days), and an hour ago I feel onset of a cough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wooden flute/Bansuri can be effectively cleaned externally using almond oil(wipe bansuri dry at the end), as it is said that almond oil *absorbs itself in the wood easily, and penetrates deeper.* If you also want to clean your tone holes (suggested), you should use cotton wool buds, as they are soft and absorb much. I use this method on my bansuri, and it works very well.